# The format of text of the image pasted into markdown in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

Suppose I have a file called `test.md`
I have set the following in vscode so that the images are always saved to the `test-img` folder in the same directory

```
"markdown.copyFiles.destination": {
    "**/*": "${documentBaseName}-img/"
}
```

If I paste an image, the text in markdown is this, is good。

```
![Alt text](test-img/Clip_20240109_142014.png)
```

But I sometimes refer to files in the upper directory like this

```
The rawdata is [here](../DATA/QE-plus/20240109_xxx.raw)
```

They all worked well, but I just wanted them to look tidy
Can I change the settings so that the pasted image becomes the following text

```
![Alt text](./test-img/Clip_20240109_142014.png)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy enough to just paste and later perform a Replace All and replace ```![Alt text](test-img/``` with ```![Alt text](./test-img/```. Sometimes, it's worth not overcomplicating things ;-)